# How to send back calendar data as JSON

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

I am using the full calendar gem http://fullcalendar.io/
My user gives his availabilities by selecting multiple time slots through the calendar.
Concerning UI, I didn't manage to achieve two things:

- prevent user from selecting slots that overlap on multiple days
- when user ticks the all day slot, it should also select the whole row concerning that day.

On the back end side, I have a disponibility table with a column (string) for each day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, ...).
So far, I have been extracting data from the calendar when the user creates events in it and putting them as JSON-format in a hidden field which is then sent to my back end. Here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
  var array_dispo = []

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView:  'agendaWeek',
    lang:         "fr",
    header:       false,
    timezone:     'local',
    minTime:      "08:00:00",
    columnFormat: 'dddd',
    selectHelper: true,
    selectable:   true,
    select: function(start, end) {
      var eventData = {
        start: start,
        end: end,
        block:  true,
      };

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
      var day         = moment(eventData.start["_d"]).format("dddd");
      var start_time  = moment(eventData.start["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
      var end_time    = moment(eventData.end["_d"]).format("HH:mm");
      var slot        = {
        day: day,
        start_time: start_time,
        end_time: end_time
      };
      array_dispo.push(slot);

      $("#dispo_array").val(JSON.stringify(array_dispo));
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
    editable:     true,
    eventLimit:   true,
    eventClick: function(event) {
      if(confirm('Voulez-vous supprimer cette dispo?')) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',event._id);
      }
    },

    selectOverlap: function(event) {
      return ! event.block;
    }
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, when the user clicks on a previously created event or when he chooses the resize the timeslot of a previously created event, this script doesn't update the data that is sent in the hidden field. I have been struggling to do that so far.

Here's what my view looks like:

```
 div id= "calendar"



     = form_tag tournament_disponibilities_path(@tournament), method: :post do
            = text_field_tag(:dispo_array)
            = button_tag :submit
```

and here's how I treat the JSON that is sent to my back end with my create method in disponibility_controller:

```
def create
    @disponibility            = Disponibility.new
    @disponibility.tournament = @tournament
    authorize @disponibility
disponibilities           = JSON.parse(params[:dispo_array])
      @disponibility.user       = current_user
      @disponibility.monday     = disponibilities_for_day(disponibilities, 'lundi')
      @disponibility.tuesday    = disponibilities_for_day(disponibilities, 'mardi')
      @disponibility.wednesday  = disponibilities_for_day(disponibilities, 'mercredi')
      @disponibility.thursday   = disponibilities_for_day(disponibilities, 'jeudi')
      @disponibility.friday     = disponibilities_for_day(disponibilities, 'vendredi')
      @disponibility.saturday   = disponibilities_for_day(disponibilities, 'samedi')
      @disponibility.sunday     = disponibilities_for_day(disponibilities, 'dimanche')
```

end

```
  def disponibilities_for_day(disponibilities, day)
    day_disponibilities = disponibilities.select { |hash| hash['day'] == day }
    day_disponibilities.map { |hash| "#{hash['start_time']}-#{hash['end_time']}" }.join(', ')
  end
```

Can you help me update the calendar script to achieve these goals?

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Comment: @sawa I tried my best